# How to correctly route a Gitlab installation in a subdirectory through an SSL reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, docker, gitlab

I am currently struggling with routing a Gitlab installation through an SSL reverse proxy to have Gitlab respond at the path https://myserver/git.

I am using the `sameersbn/gitlab` Docker image and an nginx web server as the reverse proxy.

Without SSL, I use the following environment configuration for Gitlab:

- GITLAB_PORT: 80
- GITLAB_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT: /git
- GITLAB_HOST: myserver

My `site-config` for nginx looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name myserver;


    location /git {
        proxy_pass      http://gitlab/git;

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host           $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }

}
```

The reverse proxy is also a Docker container which links my Gitlab container as hostname `gitlab`.

This works - going to http://myserver/git redirects me to the login page.

However, when changing it to SSL:

- GITLAB_PORT: 443
- GITLAB_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT: /git
- GITLAB_HOST: myserver
- GITLAB_HTTPS: true
- SSL_SELF_SIGNED: true

and

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myserver;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/server.key;

    location /git {
        proxy_pass      http://gitlab/git;

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host           $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
    }

}
```

does not work. When calling `https://myserver/git`, it tries to redirect to `http://localhost.my.company.domain.com/git/users/sign_in` which does not exist.

When I use `curl -k -L -vvv https://myserver/git` I see that nginx redirects me to `http://localhost/git/users/sign_in`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you intending to use SSL on both the client and upstream connection. In which case, `proxy_path` should specify `https://` as the scheme.

Answer (score 1):

The following was missing in `site-config`:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
```